# Is there a coordinate algebra library for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, coordinate-systems

I am trying to do things like:

1. Given two line segments, find if they intersect.
2. Find the area of an arbitrary Polygon

For everything I have a point in rectangular co-ordinate system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for finding the area: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/

intersection of two lines: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)